# How to repair contact form?

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, contact-form

I have a script here from an old design to a contact form and I have been unable to work for a few days. I don't know anything from Django Rest Framework and API. Could someone help me to make this script work without all of captcha. Captcha has to be removed from this script anyway. The problem is that after filling and sending the contact form I don't get the message to the email address.

**views.py**

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status

from django.conf import settings
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

from visualcaptcha import Captcha, Session
import os


class ContactView(APIView):
    u"""Widok wysyłający wiadomość email"""

    def post(self, request):
        u"""Metoda wysyłająca wiadomość email.

        Parameters
        ----------
        request : rest_framework.request.Request
            Obiekt żądania HTTP

        Returns
        -------
        rest_framework.response.Response
            Obiekt odpowiedzi HTTP.
        """

        assetsPath = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR,
                                  r'visualcaptcha', r'assets')
        visualCaptcha = Captcha(Session(request.session), assetsPath)
        frontendData = visualCaptcha.getFrontendData()
        imageField = request.data.pop(frontendData['imageFieldName'], None)
        audioField = request.data.pop(frontendData['audioFieldName'], None)

        captcha_valid = False

        if imageField is not None:
            captcha_valid = visualCaptcha.validateImage(imageField)
        if audioField is not None:
            captcha_valid = visualCaptcha.validateAudio(audioField)

        if not captcha_valid:
            print("hakuna matata")
            return Response({
                'status': 'Bad request',
                'message': (_('The captcha sent was not valid')),
                'errors': {
                    'invalid_captcha': 'The captcha sent was not valid'
                }
            }, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        try:
            subject = (request.data['subject'])
            message = (
                u'''coins-sell.pl wiadomość od użytkownika %s
                email: %s
                wiadomość:
                %s''') % (
                request.data['name'], request.data['email'],
                request.data['message'])
            from_email = request.data['email']
            recipient_list = ['kontakt@coins-sell.pl']
            html_message = render_to_string(
                'emails/contactEmail.html',
                {'name': request.data['name'],
                    'email': request.data['email'],
                    'message': request.data['message']
                 })
            send_mail(
                subject=subject,
                message=message,
                from_email=from_email,
                recipient_list=recipient_list,
                html_message=html_message
            )
            return Response({
                'status': 'OK',
                'message': (
                    _('Email was sent succesfully'))
            }, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        except Exception as e:
            return Response({
                'status': 'Bad request',
                'message': (
                    _('Message could not be sent')),
                'errors': {'exception': str(e)}
            }, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**form.html**

```
  <form name="vm.contact_form">
    <label for="contact__name">Imię</label>
      <input type="text" name="contact_name" id="contact__name">
        <strong>Pole wymagane.</strong><br><br>

    <label for="contact__email">Email</label>
      <input type="email" name="contact_email" id="contact__email" required>
        <strong>Pole wymagane.</strong><br><br>

    <!-- <label for="contact__subject">Temat</label>
      <select name="contact_subject" id="contact__subject" required></select>
        <strong>Pole wymagane.</strong><br><br> !-->

    <label for="contact__message">Wiadomość</label>
      <textarea name="contact_message" id="contact__message" required></textarea>
        <strong>Pole wymagane.</strong><br><br>

    <button type="submit">Wyślij</button>
  </form>
```

**settings.py**

```
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'mail0.mydevil.net'
EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '************'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'my_password'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'example@example.com'
MANAGERS = (('George Example', 'example@example.com'),)
```

Please, be patient and sorry for my bad English and lack of knowledge, cause I'm a student.

Comment: I need to add some Ajax script in Vue.js to my html file. Anyone know what can I do?